# Parse- check if value exist in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform

I use Parse in java script. I wrote a little code in cloud code, And now I am trying to check if an array contain an object.

I get an object by query to the db.  And then for this object I try to

```
 //items is an array inside the object
object.get('items').indexOf(item)>=0
```

In the db I can see that this item in the items array. but it always return -1.

Their is another way to check?

Comment: What is the type of item? If this is object, then indexOf won't work, since it only compares reference, not properties of object.

Comment: Clarification to Kamil's question:
[{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}].indexOf({a:1}) = -1

Comment: so how can I check? loop on them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) before to map each item by his identifier.

Some like:

```
[{mykey: "a"}, {mykey: "b"}].map(function(val){ return val.mykey; }).indexOf("a") >= 0 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [findWhere](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) method from [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) for this

```
var items = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {c: 3}];
// this returns undefined if not found or will return the item if found
_.findWhere(items, {a: 1});
```

Comment: lodash has a similar feature in _.findIndex